# Jquery: how to get array of data in form?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the data in a form with array names (name_obj[]) but I can't get it work...

My code:

```
<select name="famille[]" class="fam"><option value="4">Balistes (Balistidae)</option><option value="5">Blennies (Blenniidae)</option></select>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nbre[]" size="3" class="nomb">
<select name="famille[]" class="fam"><option value="4">Balistes (Balistidae)</option><option value="5">Blennies (Blenniidae)</option></select>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nbre[]" size="3" class="nomb">
<select name="famille[]" class="fam"><option value="4">Balistes (Balistidae)</option><option value="5">Blennies (Blenniidae)</option></select>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nbre[]" size="3" class="nomb">
<div id="calculer">Calculer</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("body").on("click", "#calculer", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var familles = $('input:text.fam').serialize();
            var nombres = $('input:text.nomb').serialize();
            console.log(familles);
});
```

Any idea to get the data?
Thanks

Comment: `<select>` is not an `input:text`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var familles = [];
var nombres = [];

$("body").on("click", "#calculer", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputs = $("form :input") 
    //console.log(inputs);

    $.each(inputs, function (k, el) {
        if ( $(el).hasClass('fam') ) {
            familles.push($(el).val());
        } else if ( $(el).hasClass('nomb') ) {
            nombres.push($(el).val());
        }
    });
    console.log(familles);
    console.log(nombres);
});
```

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6b/3/

Comment: `Jquery: how to get array of data in form?`

Comment: Yes, that's better! Is there a way to name each variable (famille=xx and nombre=xxx)? The return is all the fields raw

Comment: I'm not sure :-( I need to post it with ajax and get it with php but I  don't know how to get familles and nombre separatly...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw you jsfiddle. But it miss some data: I have only 2 values of familles...

Comment: Ok, there was an error on your html code, the class of the last select was not defined correctly. Now it works, I'll try to get these data, thanks! Please update your answer and I can validate it.